# Como ordenar array usando sort

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho um array de objetos que retorna 3 possiveis valores de sensibilidade: "LOW", "MEDIUM", "HIGH". Porém com o codigo abaixo ele está ordenando em "HIGH - MEDIUM e LOW" respectivamente em ordem crescente e eu desejo que retorne "HIGH - MEDIUM e LOW". O que posso corrigir neste codigo?

Nesta função faço a comparação das sensibilidades recebidas no array

```
  orderItemsByOrderOption = (items) => {
switch (this.state.selectedOrderOption.column) {
  case "sensitivity":
    return items.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.sensitivity > b.sensitivity) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.sensitivity < b.sensitivity) {
        return -1;
      }
      // a must be equal to b
      return 0;
    });
```

Comment: Como são objetos você pode criar um atributo no objeto para determinar o nível da sensibilidade, usando um número inteiro por exemplo e ordenar por esse atributo.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Ordenar array dentro de outro array com ReactJS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/487182/ordenar-array-dentro-de-outro-array-com-reactjs)